# Dynamically Inject Cognito User Pool Id

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to set up my Angular app that runs on AWS so that it will use the Cognito user pool ID for development when we deploy to anywhere other than production and then use the production pool in that case. (I spent a lot of time trying to find a way to have AWS just tell me what pool is active where I'm running but I couldn't figure out a way to make that work)

I added the cognito ID's for dev in the environment.ts file and the ones for production in the environment.prod.ts file in my Angular project.  In the buildspec.yaml we run "ng build" and from testing this out, I know that I can get this to work if I change that to "ng build --configuration production" to access the ID's in the environment.prod.ts file.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to specify the environment in the buildspec.yaml file.  I want to do something like this:

`ng build --configuration $ENVIRONMENT`

Where that evaluates to either development or production depending on which pipeline deploy we are doing.

Please let me know what if any other files it would be helpful to see.

buildspec.yaml

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
      - pip3 install cfn-lint
      - npm install
      - npm install -g @angular/cli
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - cfn-lint application-stack.yaml pipeline/*.yaml

  build:
    commands:
      - cd MyProject
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - npm install
      - ng build --configuration $ENVIRONMENT
      # - ng test --watch=false
      - cd -
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t my-project-api:$COMMIT_ID api
      - docker tag my-project-api:$COMMIT_ID $API_REPO:$COMMIT_ID
      - docker push $API_REPO:$COMMIT_ID
      - docker build -t my-project:$COMMIT_ID MyProject
      - docker tag my-project:$COMMIT_ID $UI_REPO:$COMMIT_ID
      - docker push $UI_REPO:$COMMIT_ID
      - sed -i "s/=ImageTag=/${COMMIT_ID}/" config/*.json
      - sed -i "s/=BranchName=/${BRANCH_NAME}/" config/*.json
      - sed -i "s/=Username=/${USERNAME}/" config/*.json

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  name: config
  discard-paths: yes
  base-directory: config
```

Answer (score 0):

In the development pipeline set the environment variable:

[image]

In the production pipeline set the environment variable:

[image]

Reference it using this command in buildspec.yml:

```
    build:
    commands:
        - ng build --configuration="$ENVIRONMENT"
```

Do the file replacement in angular.json

```
     "development": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ]

     "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prd.ts"
            }
          ]
```

Comment: Where in the buildspec.yaml would that live?  I need to put it in there.

Comment: Under the build section  like you have it now. Try putting quotes arround your env variable. Also not related to this, but you do not need to install npm again in the build section.

Comment: So in your example you specify development as the value, how would I change that to production for that case?

Comment: My example is for the development pipeline. For production in your production pipeline you would set the ENVIRONMENT variable to have a value of 'production' and in your angular.json you would have section for 'production' that copies for example environment.production.ts to environment.ts

Comment: I have updated my answer with some more details.

Comment: The problem in my case is that we have one deploy pipeline that pushes to either dev or prod based on pipeline steps.  Someone else here had an idea about a way to possibly handle my case that I am going to try but I agree that in the case where  you had multiple pipelines that should work

Comment: If you have only one build pipeline, then you still do the same as I suggested but under your build section in AWS Pipeline you will have TWO build actions next to each other. One for production and one for development. They will build in parallel.